# Javascript - convert date to something easier to read (month name)

Tags: javascript

I am using the Wordpress API to display posts and I would like to convert the date to something more user friendly. The date that is returned looks like this:

```
2019-12-07T20:06:42
```

I found this function which makes it a little easier to read:

```js
var date = "2019-12-07T20:06:42";
function convertDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return month + " " + day + ", " + year;
}
console.log(convertDate(new Date(date)));
```

I would like to take this a step further and make it so that it displays the month name rather than the number. How can I update this function to accomplish that? Desired output would look like this:

```
December 07, 2019
```

Comment: Create an array like `const monthNames = ["January", "February", ...];` and index it.

Comment: If you want more formatting options, use the `moment.js` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the built-in [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to display that date as a string for a specific locale.

To achieve the format you want we'll use the following for the options:

```
{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' }
```

```js
var date = new Date("2019-12-07T20:06:42");
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
```

Comment: Wow, excellent, no need for the custom function at all. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. I didn't know `toLocaleString` took an options object as a second argument. That makes it way more useful.

Answer (score 0):

basically you have to do it manually using an array, like this:

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var date = "2019-12-07T20:06:42";

function convertDate(date) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  // just access the index of the months name, that is all. 
  // remove 1 because the array is base 0.
  return months[month - 1] + " " + day + ", " + year;
}
console.log(convertDate(new Date(date)));
```

using a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will help you to display it more easily and with tons of different formats like specified [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

You could call a `getMonthName` function and pass it the index of the month, like:

```js
var date = "2019-12-07T20:06:42";
function convertDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return getMonthName(monthIndex) + " " + day + ", " + year;
}

function getMonthName(index){
  const list = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";  
  return list.split(",")[index];
}

console.log(convertDate(new Date(date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and pass the option `month: "long"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat